# OL 4 - Only first marker (feature) is active, why?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm a total beginner on OL - just a genealogy site owner trying to save the maps I depend on, from G**gle cutting me off at June 11. "No CC info = No maps..."

All maps are visible and work, except the most basic one.
I'm using OL 4.6.5. Here's an example of that map: https://xerxx.se/clicktest.html
My problem is that only the first marker reacts for mouseclick and hover. I have tried both these solutions that I found at this site:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(event) {
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature,layer) {
    alert("A SC NAME = *"+feature.get('name')+"*");
    });
});

/*
map.on('singleclick', function(e) {
  var iconFeatureA = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(e.pixel);
  if (iconFeatureA !== null) {
    var name = iconFeatureA[0].get("name");
    alert("B SC NAME = *"+name+"*");
    e.preventDefault(); // avoid bubbling 
  }
}); 
*/
```

The first snippet is currently used in that example.
I managed to make the heatmap example here https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/earthquake-clusters.html into something that works **really nice** - example: https://xerxx.se/heattest.html
Each singleplace marker show info so I tried to build the basic map like that (reading a .kml-string) but it was also only the first marker that was "active". (And I couldn't get the markers in different colours)

Please: Can someone explain how I can get all markers active like in the heatmap - I'm desperate: I don't want to give G**gle my CC info!
I need no more that a JS alert() - the pop-ups ("text balloons") can be added later.

**Thank You In Advance**,
Erik - 100% OL novice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. The coordinates are not.

Valid coordinates are in the range [-180;180]. Your place 2 point is at

```
 var lon = 291.620235443;
```

set it to

```
var lon = 291.620235443 - 360;
```

and it will work.

If you use your browser debugger, you will see that, with the current map, the function `map.on('singleclick', function(event) {...});` is called for point #2, but no feature is found at this location.

Comment: @xerxx great! Please consider accepting the answer (green check mark to the left) so others know it is a working solution

Comment: Done! Thanks also for _this_ explanation. X